# What code format shows proper line breaks?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, format, ascii

I am exporting some Access tables to txt files and there are a lot of problems with the txt file. One of those problems being line breaks not visible in the txt file itself. If I copy a line with a line break into Notepad++ from Notepad, it'll break into 2 lines.

So I believe this may be a code format problem, but I can't find the proper one to resolve this. I'm currently exporting to the default Western European, but should I export tot UTF, Unicode, ASCII or something else?

Comment: The question is rather vague. It probably relates to different line break conventions (mainly LF vs. CR vs. CR LF) rather than character encoding or code format.

Comment: Oh, doing just some quick searching, I think it's more likely line break convention-related. Is there any way to control this within Access or a text-editor?

Answer (score 1):

When exporting from MS Access (or VB/VBA in general), make sure you're using vbCrLf constant (Carriage Return plus Line Feed) for line breaks. That constant corresponds to HEX values 0D 0A.

In Windows, it is a convention to use the above 2 characters together as line breaks, while in many other platforms, such as Unix/Linux/MacOS/etc. typically just 0A is used.

That brings up an issue: Notepad, the standard Windows text file viewer, cannot deal with 0A alone and does not treat such symbols as line breaks. More advanced editors, such as Notepad++ or UltraEdit, display such files correctly, though.

Comment: Thanks. How do I check and see if I'm using vbCrLf constant for line breaks?

Comment: If you're exporting your data from MS Access using VBA code, that should be evident in your code. If you're using some other method, then I can only guess...

Answer (score 0):

The CSV export function in Microsoft Office applications (Excel, Access) terminate a data row with CR+LF and write for a line break within a data value (multi-line string) just LF  into the file. (I think just CR was written into the CSV file for a line break in older versions of Office before Office 2007.)

Most text editors detect those LF without CR (respectively CR without LF) and convert them to CR+LF on loading the CSV file which results on viewing of the CSV file in text editor in supposed wrong CSV lines as number of data values is not correct on data rows with data values containing a line break.

However, newline characters within a double quoted value in a CSV file are correct according to CSV specification as described in Wikipedia article about [Comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

But most applications with support on import from CSV file do not support CSV files with newline characters within a double quoted value and therefore some data values are imported wrong. Also regular expression replaces can't be done on a CSV file with newline characters within a data value because the number of separator character is not constant on all lines.

UltraEdit has for editing such CSV files with only LF (or CR) for a line break within a data value a special configuration setting. At **Advanced - Configuration - File Handling - DOS/Unix/Mac Handling** the option *Never prompt to convert files to DOS format* or *Prompt to convert if file is not DOS format* with clicking on button *No* if this prompt is displayed must be selected and additionally *Only recognize DOS terminated lines (CR/LF) as new lines for editing* must be enabled.

The CSV file with CR+LF for end of data row and only LF (or CR) for a line-break within a data value is loaded with those settings in UltraEdit with number of lines equal the number of data rows. And the line-feeds without carriage return (respectively the carriage returns without line-feed) in the CSV file are displayed as character in the lines with a small rectangle as no font has a glyph for a carriage return or line-feed defined because they are whitespace characters with no width. A Perl regular expression find searching for `\r(?!\n)|\n(?<!\r)` can be used now to find those line breaks within data values and replace them with something different like a space character or remove them.

Which character encoding (ASCII, ANSI, Unicode (UTF-16), UTF-8) to use on export depends on which characters can exist in string values. A Unicode encoding is necessary if string values can have also characters not included in local code page.